# A form of the Mathieu equation into autonomous system

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having a really hard time trying to find the autonomous system form for the following equation:

$\ddot x=-cos(t)x$

My problem is clear, how the do I fix the variables so my the system does not depend of $t$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We start with

$\ddot x = (-\cos t) x; \tag 1$

we set

$y = \dot x, \tag 2$

so that

$\dot y = \ddot x; \tag 3$

then (1) becomes

$\dot y = (-\cos t)x; \tag 4$

we now introduce a third $t$-dependent variable $z(t)$ satisfying

$\dot z = 1 \tag 5$

along with the initial condition

$z(t_0) = t_0 \tag 6$

for some

$t_0 \in \Bbb R; \tag 7$

the unique solution to (5)-(6) is

$z(t) = t; \tag 8$

we substitute this into (4), yielding

$\dot y = (-\cos z) x; \tag 9$

we have thus reduced (1) to the first-order autonomous system

$\dot x = y, \tag{10}$

$\dot y = (-\cos z)x, \tag{11}$

$\dot z = 1, \; z(t_0) = t_0, \tag{12}$

leaving the initial values $x(t_0)$, $y(t_0)$ yet to be supplied.